# Why a "Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response'" error is raised after destructuring the response object

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

I'm implementing my own `fetch` method that uses the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
While doing this I've encountered a raised error that I cannot explain.

**The code** fragment looks like this:

```js
    const response: Response = await fetch(url, options);
    const { json } = response;

    return json();
```

**The problem** is that this code triggers a promise rejection:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked

I know that the `json` method can only be called once, which it does.
The `fetch` itself doesn't fail. If I return directly `response.json()`, no rejection arises.

**My question** is why using the destructuring assignment on the `response` object, locks the `body` of the response which is a `ReadableStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that destructuring the object results in decoupling the `json` method from the original scope of the `response`.

One **solution** would be:

```js
    const response: Response = await fetch(url, options);
    const { json } = response;

    return json.bind(response)();
```